# Simple questions on 明け方

Tags: words, usage

So  明け方 means "dawn," but if looked at more closely, is the literal meaning of 明け方, "in the direction of dawn"?

I think this is wrong, but I can't remember which meaning of 方 is taken here.

Is it the meaning of 方 as 様子 or "state," as in "the state of dawn/light breaking?"

Also, what is the difference in tone and usage between 明け方 and 明け ( when  明け is used as "dawn")?

Answer (score 3):

明鏡国語辞典 lists it as an additional meaning (二６), おおよその時間。その時分。
What it lists as sense 二１ comes pretty close to its general meaning and how it is used here:

> 「その事をする方法・手段。**また、その様子・有様。**」

Perhaps you could think of it like this?

作り方=how to make food

明け方=how it becomes bright=as it becomes bright=dawn

Pitch accent, see ＮＨＫ日本語発音アクセント辞典

```
　　＿＿＿＿
　あけか°た [=flat, か° is a nasal が (鼻音,ɳa)]
　　＿
　あけ
```

As for how they're different in meaning, there's a good explanation in the 語例解辞典.

> 【使い分け】
>
> (１)「明け方」は、夜が開ける時間帯をいうのに対し、「夜明け」「明け」は夜が明けること、あるいはその時をいい、さらにそれを中心とする時間帯をいう場合もある。
>
> (2)「夜明け」は、「アジアの夜明け」のように新しい時代、好ましい変革の到来を意味することもある。
>   [*yoake* can be used idiomatically in the sense of "dawn of a new age"]
>
> 【使い方】
>
> (明け)
>
> 深夜から明けにかけて暴走族が騒いでいる (this is about その時)
>
> 明けの明星
>
> (明け方)
>
> 明け方が近く、雷がなった
>
> 翌日の明け方に目的地についた (both are concerned with 夜が開ける時間帯)

Also, 明け seems to be used more in compounds (忌明け,休み明け,精進明け,梅雨明け,年明け,正月明け), while 明け方 is usually an individual word.夜明け (,perhaps because it is longer and a fully formed idea [??],) can be seen as an individual words in phrases such as 「夜明けにはまだ間がある」 or 「夜明けを待つ」

Comment: I had thought it was the meaning of kata meaning 様子 but when I looked it up, this was not listed on tangorin so perhaps it is their inadequacy that caused my confusion. Thanks for your work.

Comment: "明け方=how it becomes bright=as it becomes bright=dawn". While this is probably correct etymologically, it could potentially be misleading, since あけがた "dawn" and あけかた "how it becomes bright" are separate words in MJ.